Compare 2 columns using QUERY function in Google Sheets
I'm comparing 2 columns, where some values are missing from column B (1st column).
Can you please help me how to use =QUERY function to return missing values?
I know that I can use =FILTER, =MATCH, and =ISNA function, but I was told to use =QUERY function.
This is the function that I tried:
=QUERY(B3:B, "SELECT B WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND B NOT IN (D3:D)", 0) 

Are you trying to exclude values for B that are reflected in Column D? You could use  =QUERY(B3:B,"SELECT * WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND NOT B MATCHES '"&textjoin("|",1,D3:D)&"' ",0)

please see link to google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174pfMWSyjO5-uvRMKbAQY9yAJ3eAlGA2CeKhg52lCKs/edit?usp=sharing

anyone can help please

I added an answer for you using query function.

Suppose your data has two columns: column B is complete and column D has one empty value.
Case 1
If you meant copying all data from column D with the empty cell excluded, you can use:
=QUERY(B2:D6, "SELECT D WHERE D IS NOT NULL", 0)

Output screenshot:
case-1
Case 2
If you meant returning a cell in column B which correspondent cell in column D is null, you can use:
=QUERY(B2:D6, "SELECT B WHERE D IS NULL", 0)

Output screenshot:
case-2
Case 3
Or perhaps you want to get all cells in column B which corresponding cell within the same row in column D is not empty. In that case you can use:
=QUERY(B2:D6, "SELECT B WHERE D IS NOT NULL", 0)

Output screenshot:
case-3
Remember that you can also filter cells which match a certain value within the specified range using the =QUERY function in Google Sheets. For example:
=QUERY(B2:D6, "SELECT B WHERE D < 1000", 0)
=QUERY(B2:D6, "SELECT D WHERE B = 'Eric'", 0)

You can access my Google Sheets document using this link.

thanks
unfortunately it doesnt work I pasted the link below so you can see what im trying to do
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/174pfMWSyjO5-uvRMKbAQY9yAJ3eAlGA2CeKhg52lCKs/edit?usp=sharing

please see the link what im trying to do

Try this
=QUERY(A:A,"select A where not A matches '"&textjoin("|",true,C:C)&"' ")


thanks, it works,
can you please explain the string, I dont understand it.
thanks
